Manga/manhua series where the leading lady dies in the first chapter and her husband finally has regrets
I'm trying to remember the title of a manhua. It was historical fiction, maybe fantasy as well?
In the first chapter, a woman is sitting, waiting on her husband and lamenting the fact that he is so distant with her and their son. He is complaining and writing off everything she brings up, including her asking him to visit his son more. He says something along the lines of "I saw him last week." She then remarks internally that she has been given poisoned tea again, but while other times she's been careful, this time she drinks it and allows herself to die. The husband had turned to leave, but seeing her collapse makes him come back. She says something along the lines of "Let's not meet in our next life," or "I hope we never meet again."
My memory of the art style is foggy, but I believe the husband and son were shown and they both had black hair; it's possible she did as well. I think she wears a green dress when she's meeting with him.
I also know one other point is that the husband becomes angry when a relative, an aunt I think, admits to doing it with little remorse, but this is in a different chapter.
It had a fantasy element; I believe it was time regression rather than reincarnation. It hinted that time regressed for her, but that her husband may have had something to do with it, as he gets revenge on the family member that poisoned her tea.

Were there any actual sci-fi or fantasy elements (such as reincarnation or time regression) that would make this on-topic here?

So did time regress after the wife died, bringing her back to life?

Who regressed, the husband or the wife? Because it sounds like the husband is the main character.

The manhwa is Now Come and Regret.

In a world where power dictates fate, Princess Ines of a fallen kingdom is ensnared by Ryan, a captivating yet ambitious captor. Despite his efforts to dominate her spirit, Ines resists, challenging his every move with a fiery defiance that slowly transforms disdain into obsession. As their tumultuous dynamic unfolds, a brush with death shifts everything. Ryan, confronted by the depth of his feelings, faces a choice that could redefine them both.
Their story of power, resistance, and the unforeseen force of love questions whether hearts hardened by ambition can truly change.
Will Ines' near escape bring them closer, or will it be the catalyst that tears their world apart?

Details I missed: the names are Ines, Ryan, and their son, Cesar. Ines and Cesar share black hair, Ryan and Cesar both have green eyes. Apparently, there is fantasy, because Ines has a being that is watching over her but takes her life force.

Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. However, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.
